# How can I limit the length of a string to 150 characters?

Tags: c#

I tried the following:

```
var a = description.Substring(0, 150);
```

However this gives a problem if the length of description is less than 150 chars. So is there another way I can limit the length to 150 that won't give an error when string length is for example 20.

Answer (score 36):

```
var a = description == null 
        ? string.Empty 
        : description.Substring(0, Math.Min(150, description.Length));
```

Answer (score 23):

```
var a = description.Substring(0, Math.Min(150, description.Length));
```

Just grab the substring of either 150 characters, or the whole string, whichever is shorter.

Answer (score 12):

Try the following extension method

```
public static string LimitTo(this string data, int length) {
  return (data == null || data.Length < length) 
    ? data 
    : data.Substring(0, length);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The String Length Attribute works for C#:

```
[StringLength(150)]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have tested it in a ViewModel in WPF and it doesn't work with a TextBox. The documentation mentions ASP.NET. Maybe it's used only in that kind of applications.

Answer (score 4):

It will be good if your environment support you to use below method. (As [@christian-cody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2624494/christian-cody) suggested.)

```
[StringLength(150)]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

You have to include the below namespace to use it.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you actually want this.

```
public static string LimitTo(this string data, int length) {
  return (data == null || data.Length <= length)   // Less than or equal to
    ? data 
    : data.Substring(0, length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, even if you could create an instance that worked the way you wanted, as soon as you assign another value to your variable, it would be a different instance of type `string`.

If you want a `string` property that has a max of 150 characters, then write a property where you check the value in the setter and throw an exception if it's more than 150 characters.

If you want a `string` parameter to a method that has a max of 150 characters, then at the top of the method, check to see if it is more than 150 characters, if it is, throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = description.Substring(0, description.Length > 150 ? 150 : description.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

everyone seems to be overcomplicating this, all you need is simply

```
var a = description;
if (description.length > 150) a = description.Substring(0, 150);
```

sometimes you just need to think around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As of C# 8.0 we can utilize the [Range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes) and end up with this:

```
var x = description[..150];
```

Comment: This only works if the the string is >= 150 characters. If the string is < 150 characters, this will throw an ArgumentOutOfRange exception.